# SnackBar - Exponential Backoff with Retry functionality

Tags: android, android-snackbar

I am trying to use SnackBar to notify users, if they are not connected to internet. How do I implement "Exponential back-off algorithm" for SnackBar with "Retry" action to check Internet Connectivity?

Here is what i am doing now..

I am using an AsyncTask to check for Internet Connectivity. If there is no connectivity, I am showing the SnackBar with Retry Action. When user clicks on Retry, I increment the back-off value(will set the value to twice the previous value - temporarily), dismissing the old SnackBar and showing a new SnackBar. Now when the timer runs out, I check for connectivity again, and if its still not there, I re-show the SnackBar with back-off value increased.

What is the best way of implementing SnackBar in this situation? Is there a simple solution to this situation, other than my approach?

Comment: did you find the solution?